# How do I change or remove my FACE.ID from Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, login, biometrics

Okay, so does anyone know how to change or remove a FACE.ID in Windows 8?

I set up the FACE.ID  but the stupid thing can’t even recognize my face half the time so I want to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Hit the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key on your keyboard, then start typing “faceID.”

Open the application and you’ll find options to manage users.